# Change icon in react-native-navigation tab

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Is that possible to change icon in `react-native-navigation` tabbar? 

I mean for example somewhere in my application i did call to api and after response came I need to change my `Icon` in tab bar to new one. 

 for example `Heart` icon to `Mail` Icon.

Appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Give us some code ma dude !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [setTabButton](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=settabbuttonparams-)

```
this.props.navigator.setTabButton({
  tabIndex: 0, // (optional) if missing, the icon will be added to this screen's tab
  icon: require('../img/one.png'), // local image asset for the tab icon unselected state (optional)
  selectedIcon: require('../img/one_selected.png'), // local image asset for the tab icon selected state (optional, iOS only)
  label: 'New Label' // tab label that appears under the icon (optional)
});
```

Comment: @АндрейГузюк How to change icon's color. I am only seeing a blue icon. Icon however is of black color.

Comment: Found the solution by setting this property *disableIconTint: true*